# A shell script that checks if the nginx service is running, with action

Tags: bash, shell, cron

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
getpid=$(pgrep nginx | wc -l 
if [ "$getpid" > 0 ]
then
  echo 'Nginx is Fine, It is Running at' $date
else
  echo "Error on Nginx and stoped at" $date
  sudo fuser -k 443/tcp
  sudo service nginx start
  sudo service  monit start
  sudo monit monitor all
  echo "Error on Nginx and stoped at" $date | mailx -s "The Nginx Stop - But it is Fixed" -A /root/nginx_log3.txt mymail.com
fi
exit 0;
```

I see several ways to check the service:

```
$(ps ax | grep myName | fgrep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

or

```
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 0 ))
```

and several ways...

innumerable means of checking if a process is running, but the problem, is that even though I terminate `nginx`, any command using PS always brings many results with `pid` values! since `pgrep` always shows 0 after I do service nginx stop, and the `gprep` seems perfect to compare with value 0 which is less than any pid,

because if it has run, always show pid above velor 0, `pgrep` is the path , but the problem is that I have a `crontab` that runs this script every 3 minutes, and even with the process running, with a pid greater than zero, it is restarting the service!

I found several blogs teaching several scripts for this, but none works!

I have the `monit` to keep the services alive, but sometimes it fails.

clearly I am not sure how to compare the values, of the extracted pid with the value 0:

```
getpid=$(pgrep nginx | wc -l)
    if [ "$getpid" > 0 ]
```

because the service is always restarting every 3 minutes, even the service running with a pid running (value greater than 0)

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Does your init system not have a way of checking a service’s status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would maybe check the www services that you are trying to serve instead of if the service is running. Take a look at these various examples :

```
    https=$(nc -z localhost 443)
    http=$(nc -z localhost 80)
    netstt_cnt=$(netstat -ntlp | grep httpd | wc -l)

    http_issues=""
    if [[ ! $https ]] || [[ ! $http ]] ;then
        http_issues=" -Http/https ports not detected "
    fi
    if [ $netstt_cnt -ne 2 ] ;then
        http_issues="${http_issues} -Netstat not reporting httpd "
    fi

    # -- if http_host_check is set perform httpd checks
    local code_stat=""
    if [[ $http_host_check ]] ;then
        http_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $http_host_check)
        if [ $http_code -lt 1 ] ;then
            http_issues="${http_issues} -Apache NOT serving pages http_code=$http_code. "
        elif [ $http_code -gt 399 ] ;then
            http_issues="${http_issues} -Apache Error http_code=$http_code on test page ${http_host_check}. "
        fi
        code_stat=", (http_code=${http_code}) "
    fi

    # -- php FPM sock, see readonly var $PHP_FPM_SOCK for use set to "" to disable this check.
    if [[ $PHP_FPM_SOCK ]] ;then
        if ! echo /dev/null | socat UNIX:${PHP_FPM_SOCK} - ;then
            http_issues="${http_issues} -php-fpm sock not communicating"
        fi
    fi

    if [[ $http_issues ]] ;then
            echo "Error on Nginx and stoped at" $date
            sudo service nginx stop
            sudo service  monit stop
            sudo fuser -k 443/tcp
            sleep 10    
            sudo service nginx start
            sudo service  monit start
            sudo monit monitor all
            if [[ $http_host_check ]] ;then
                http_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null $http_host_check)
             if [ $http_code -lt 1 ] ;then
                http_issues="${http_issues} -Apache NOT serving pages http_code=$http_code. "
            elif [ $http_code -gt 399 ] ;then
                http_issues="${http_issues} -Apache Error http_code=$http_code on test page ${http_host_check}. "
            fi
            sleep 5
            code_stat=", (http_code=${http_code}) "
            echo "Webserver had a problem, current status is $code_stat" $date | mailx -s "The Nginx stop: $code_stat" -A /root/nginx_log3.txt mymail.com  
    fi

    echo "Current Status : $http_issues"
```

Update: super simple example  added here :

```
http_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://my_domain.com/)
    if [ $http_code -lt 1 ] ;then
        echo "${http_issues} -Apache NOT serving pages http_code=$http_code. "
        // ... do something here (restart web server)..
    fi
```

Comment: Hi @Mike_Q In my tests I could not make it work, your code is far above the simple proposal of mine, just to extract the value of pid to a format that is comparable to 0, with my code I understand I can do several things, like mysql , php-fpm too, but I could not get your code working with nginx. I stop the service and it does not start back nginx like my code starts.

Comment: @Mike_Q You gave me a very good idea!! I can put a file 754fsfsf73876gsfg574sfjaks485467sfs.php to have a unique URL, and I can access this url via script, and I can do an echo in php of all those characters, in one of the sites, and do a match with a value stored in the script, if it is accessible, the match will be possible and everything is ok if it is inaccessible to match, service sevices start on all services. I'll make an Aks here on the stack!

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego  I can provide a more basic example but all you need to do is check if the http_code string is set by some checks.  ALSO you probably don't even need to make a  webpage because we are checking if CURL is valid.   For example:  curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null http://your_domain.com/  will print out 000 if your domain is down. You do not need to check the contents of the page it asked for.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego  I added a sample of what I am talking about to my post above.

Comment: Hi @mike_Q Thanks again :) ... always reboot service too! Please, see here: https://hastebin.com/avuravavey.bash  many codes and explanations.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego I should mention that you use that 'status' option. I provided code on your link that checks the services if down, restart them all. you can make them their own function etc I just provide this example.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego oh I used functions which is nice because I restart the services then call the function to check if they are running and email the status of the servers UP or DOWN ..

Comment: Hi @mike_Q Thank you so much. But as I said before, that your code is very complex for me, I do not know how to change it, ... If I can not modifier it, I can not make it work, but in the example I gave you among others I have here, made crazy in the codes without a minute of pause all day today, I was able to make 4 different codes work for that task!

Comment: @Mike_Q I've learned that using PID values for this task is the worst way, ps, pgrep, anything that works with pid values is the worst option., I've had a lot of work for being working with the improper resources. I just created a fifth code with that little simple code in your update. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @ArianeMartinsGomesDoRego , your idea is good. I just wanted to propose alternatives .  I would put them all into one script.. :-)  Good work ! Thanks for the interesting conversation !